# What impact does a higher $R^2$ have on the precision of the CI?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, r-squared

I attended a seminar today at which the presenter mentioned that a higher $R^2$ would, all other things being equal, produce a narrower confidence interval.

Is that true, and if so then why? Google searches and introspection didn't reveal to me any reason why this might be the case.

Comment: The key phrase here is, I think, 'All else being equal'. How can you keep all else equal and change the $R^2$? Something else has to change. Presumably the speaker means if all else equal except $\sigma_{\epsilon}$' in which case it is true (if you keep all else equal and increase $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ then $R^2$ will decrease and CI will increase. Both monotonically.

Comment: Confidence interval *for what parameter?*

Answer (score 0):

$$
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

If $R^2$ increases, either the numerator decreases or the denominator increases. "All else equal" tells me the $y_i$ are fixed, meaning that $\bar y = \dfrac{1}{N}\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}y_i$ is fixed, so the  denominator is not changing.

Thus, the numerator must decrease by making better predictions $\hat y_i$. (How you keep "all else equal" yet make better predictions is a mystery to me, but something has to give.) As the numerator is a measure of square loss, the numerator is related to the error term variance! This is especially true if "all else equal" means that the parameter count does not change.

Since the coefficient standard errors depend on the (estimated) error variance, decreaseing the (estimated) error variance, equivalent to increasing $R^2$, leads to smaller standard errors and narrower confidence intervals.

That is, if you can predict better, you tighten up your estimates. I feel like regression ought to work this way.

Comment: Please consider the possibility that decreasing the error variance usually is accomplished by introducing additional regressors, which in turn is known to risk greatly inflating standard errors of estimate when those new regressors are not linearly independent of the existing ones.

Comment: @whuber This could happen if two outcomes are predicted by the same sets of features, and one gives a higher $R^2$. Then that model has a lower sum of squared errors but the same VIFs (because both regressions use the same features) and parameter count. (But then the denominators change, unless a freaky coincidence means they do not. Perhaps that is what "all else equal" means.)